# program that takes a radius via input that finds the surface area and volume

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, input

```
#cube
        lengthC= input('Give me the side length of your cube')
        areaC=6*(int(lengthC)**2)
        volumeC =(int(lengthC)**3)
        print('The volume of your cube is', volumeC, 'and your area is', areaC)
```

## This is what I did for a cube so following the same format I need the same thing but for a sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exactly the same with other formulas:

```
import math

lengthC= input("Give me the side length of your cube: ")
areaC=6*(int(lengthC)**2)
volumeC =(int(lengthC)**3)
print('The volume of your cube is', volumeC, 'and your area is', areaC)

lengthR  = input("Give me the radius of the sphere: ")
volumE   = (4/3) * math.pi * (float(lengthR)**3)
areaE    = 4 * math.pi * (float(lengthR)**2)
print('The volume of your sphere is', volumE, 'and your area is', areaE)
```

output:

```
Give me the side length of your cube: 3
The volume of your cube is 27 and your area is 54
Give me the radius of the sphere: 9
The volume of your sphere is 3053.6280592892786 and your area is 1017.8760197630929
```

Answer (score 1):

surface area of a sphere is 4 pi x radius ** 2 and volume is 4/3 x pi x radius**3 so

```py
import math
radius= int(input('Give me the radius of your sphere'))
areaS=4 * math.pi * (radius**2)
volumeS = (4/3) * math.pi * (radius ** 3)
print('The volume of your sphere is', volumeS, 'and your area is', areaS)
```